# Is it possible to use a milling machine *bit* in a drill press?

Tags: drill

Reverse of "Is it possible to use a drill press as a milling machine with the proper bit?".  I'd think it would, but I imagine a CNC mill might be taking off less "material per unit time" than a drill press.  Also, would the fluting be different for a CNC mill and drill press?

Edit: I found an answer at [BladeForums](https://www.bladeforums.com/threads/end-mills-in-a-drill-press.568285/) - I'm posting it here just for reference.

Comment: Jim, if you do have a valid answer you can post it as an answer to your own question.  This feature is provided specifically so people can share answers they found on their own.  So, take a few key excerpts from your link and post that as an answer.  Just don't make a "link only" answer - that other site could change or die.

Comment: Use it, HOW, exactly? The question as asked does not make it at all obvious that you mean "the reverse of..." and the lateral forces applied by using a milling bit in a drill press tend to make the drill chuck fall off/out, which tends to be interesting in unpleasant ways. If you mean "only to drill straight down" then say that, as it's not at all implied by what you have said. With a "center cutting" or "plunge cutting" milling bit this may be acceptable, but the question needs clarification about what you intend to do with the bit.

Answer (score 3):

Mills and drills are not just random chip makers. They are totally different, and for good reason.

**End** mills are designed to work off the *ends* of the tool, i.e. they are driven laterally into the work. They are built for this kind of shear stress, *and not* to be driven axially.

**Drill bits** are designed for axial forces *not* lateral ones - they fall to pieces when driven laterally.  And drill bits have a vital feature end mills do not: the ability to *cope* with the varying tool speeds radially, **and particularly the ability to drill in the center where tool speed is zero**.  End mills simply are not made for that!

So you say these things are "the reverse of", *they are not the reverse at all*.  Using an end mill in a drill press is a completely different kind of operation than using a drill in a mill.  An end mill in a drill press doesn't make a whole lot of sense (except in rare cases.  And yes, squaring the bottom of a hole *is* one of them, because the end mill doesn't have to cut the center of the hole).

Whereas a drill in a mill makes a lot of sense.  Of course you are just drilling holes, but the mill gives you unbelievable ability to position the work precisely (especially with multiple holes that need to have a relationship with each other!) that you just don't have on a drill press.  You can also use the mill's auto-feed to maintain feeds correctly, and it typically has better control of speeds as well.

Answer (score 1):

Drill chucks are not mill chucks and a Jacobs taper is not a CAT taper. Drill chucks and Jacobs tapers are not designed to tolerate the radial/side force of an endmill. Thy can be pried apart as a result. Even if they aren't, the bearings in a drill press won't take the side load.

Endmills also have hardened shanks like taps and and drills do not. Drill chuck jaws are designed to grab onto and dig into an unhardened shank.

Mills, on the other hand are designed to take all the forces of a drill press and more. A mill is a super set of a drill press so anything a drill press can do a mill can do, except for drilling unclamped workpieces (so the piece can move to allow the drill to find the center punch hole. Always use a safety stop bolted to the table to prevent workpiece spinning, especially small parts), since all mill workpieces must be fixtured.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your "except" at the end. My drill press doesn't work well on unclamped pieces - it tends to hit them, spin them and fling them off in a random direction. Of course, often times, the only clamping for necessary is my hand, but it does _not_ like totally unclamped pieces (unless they're massive enough to resist the twist of the bit). Otherwise, excellent points and a +1 for you.

Comment: @FreeMan Well you need a safety stop bolted to the drill press table to stop uncontrollable spinning so the part stays in control, especially on small parts. Everyone should have one to be honest. Simple to make: Just a post with a hole in it for a T-nut threaded rod and a bolt. That allows it to still move so the drill finds the center punch mark but does not require your hand to oppose the drill torque. It's not a clamp or fixture but neither is it just holding it with your hands. I've drilled little 2"x1" parts this way on a free standing drill press.

Comment: I put a light overhang on mine to catch thin parts if they start to lift.